# STL C++ stl random

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, stl

нужна лямбда ф-ция генерирующая случаное число stl  генератором , нормальное развеивание . минимум -50 макс 50.  компилятор подсвечивает gen красным и требует скобку, не понимаю зачем и куда

```
auto gen = []() {
    return std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device()()},
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uid(-50, 50);
};
```

Comment: а на кой черт вы впихнули return в строку с объявлением gen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полный исправленный код с примером вызова. Генератор и распределение сделал статическими чтобы их не создавать при каждом вызове а пере-использовать созданные один раз. Вместо статических можно вынести их в объемлющую функцию.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##bY/BigIxDIbvfYqglxYVRkREp/oiyzJ02zoEZlLppB5WfPbZ6A66h83lD19I/j/@cln5zlE7jnMk35UQwWZHIfUn9SaYBs7RCVNIDL1D0gZuCqRc4QRtJDjCx@eLPmpgx@hFwuHQ83q/3@wgU3t7gl@TJsQr@qiNNvf638VCeE65b8S3CSgx8KswJrICTvAkerWtlrCtzPtCjlwyTWPxnEaThxwEPeB3bBhQcle1iIW16GKB5k8OCeBTYbD28aJ8J80MZrW6q3H8AQ)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto gen = []() {
        static std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-50, 50);
        return distr(rng);
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << gen() << " ";
}
```

Вывод:

```
37 10 -49 36 32 20 -32 -40 5 -37
```

Второй вариант с выносом в объемлющую функцию подходит если эта внешняя функция вызывается редко по сравнению с лямбда функцией. Этот вариант отличается тем что Thread-Safe т.е. безопасен при много-поточности, т.к. static переменные в первом варианте при много-поточности будут конкурировать.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##RY7RisIwEEXf8xWDC0uCCpVFRJv1R5alZJNYBtqJpBMfFL@9O9ai8zLhkHvP@PN57TtH7Th@IPmuhAg2OwqpP6o3wTRwjk6YQmLoHZI2cFMgM3A4HHre7PdfO8jU3ibw7GhCvKCP2mhzr9@/C@Ep5b6RriagVONfYUxkBRxhInq9rVawrcwz5gonaCPBN/x8/r7cj8mRS6Y5Jf45MfvEA3rAa2wYUNJVLcvCRvZyiebVMt3lU2Gw9iEShTwWsKjVXY3jPw)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-50, 50);
    auto gen = [&]() {
        return distr(rng);
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << gen() << " ";
}
```

Ещё один вариант (модификация первого static варианта), решающая проблему многопоточности добавлением мьютекса. Этот вариант медленней, зато может использоваться при многопоточности, в однопоточной среде достаточно первого варианта (первый и быстрее будет).

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##bZDRasMwDEXf/RWie3HoCimjjDZefmQM4zleEI3tzpFHWem3Z0oa1haqF5kjWfdK9nBY2c6EdhieMNguNw5UMqGJvhZXgrGn5Mwd85ncsRYCA4E3GGQBJwEcJlOE1gV4g/ePfzpGT4bQcmp2O0/r7fblFVJoTxO4qOrG/aB1spDFuXr4MQf8islr1tUNsi/8zIQxKAY1TESuNuUzbMri8YTJOfh8vC1fJn9np7to9@raWMMIJLffjEuOcgqzGq8wl2bL7A9kj79OEyCfoaw4KVhzXi6xuFe1MRMoNV6Mj8WPBSwqcR6GPw)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    auto gen = []() {
        static std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
        static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-50, 50);
        static std::mutex mux;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mux);
        return distr(rng);
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << gen() << " ";
}
```

**Дополнение.** Как предложил @ДжонниКэтсвилл, ещё можно использовать спецификатор [thread_local](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), для решения проблемы многопоточности. Т.е. следующий код безопасен в многопоточной среде и не требует использования `std::mutex`. На мой взгляд это самый лучший из всех 4х предложенных вариантов кода.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##hY/BbsIwDIbvfQqLXRIBUtGEEDTjRaYpypKsWGodlDocQDx7Z1gF3OaLrc/y7//3x@PSd47acXxD8l0JEUx2FFK/r54E08A5OmEVEkPvkJSGSwVSrnCCNhJ8wOfXg95qYMfogQ9yGmyXvOuEhd2u59V2@76BTO3lDv4@2hBP6KPSSl@b/1UK4U/KvRVHNqAYxO/CmMgI2MOdqOW6XsC61k@5HLlkmtZiYFpND0UQ1IDnaBlQEtWNNAMr6fM56hdTYsCnwmDMLbzklmEGs6a6juMv)

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto gen = []() {
        thread_local std::mt19937 rng{std::random_device()()};
        thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(-50, 50);
        return distr(rng);
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << gen() << " ";
}
```

Comment: Ещё можно использовать `thread_local` вместо `static` для многопоточного варианта.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Да действительно, можно ещё thread_local использовать, спасибо! Сейчас добавлю комментарий в ответ.